# How to add shufflejs for select tag

Tags: javascript, python, django

So I'm trying to achieve this look on shuffle.js page https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/

and I want to do it with select and option tag and how can I do it ? I'm using python and django

Here is my page:
[image]

my index.html:

```
<div class="container text-dark">
    <select class="custom-select" id="type">
        <option selected value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
        <option value="three">Three</option>
    </select>

    
    <div class="card-deck one">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">1</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">2</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">3</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card-deck two">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">4</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">5</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">6</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card-deck three">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">7</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">8</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">9</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my scrip tag:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".one").show();
        $(".two").hide();
        $(".three").hide();

        $("#type").change(function () {
            var val = $(this).val();
            if (val == "one") {
                $(".one").show();
                $(".two").hide()
                $(".three").hide();
            } else if (val == "two") {
                $(".one").hide();
                $(".two").show();
                $(".three").hide();
            } else if (val == "three") {
                $(".one").hide();
                $(".two").hide();
                $(".three").show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

So when I choose the Two value in select tag it will appear 4 5 6

Can someone show me how can I do that animation for my page

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: sorry I will fix my title

Comment: Follow the documentation of that script and when you actually get it integrated and run into specific issues show what you tried and what isn't working then. Using third party scripts takes a bit of experimentation and research on your part. Everyone has gone through that themselves but the objective here is not to do all of that initial integration for you. SO isn't  free code writing service